# Compatibility drugs info

Tags: pharmacology

Let's suppose that I take a DrugA for ProblemA and then I got this ProblemB and started to take DrugB. Are there general rules I can look up to figure out whether I can take DrugA & DrugB simultaneously?

I mean drugs can cancel each other or vice versa increase effects of each other (in an extreme extend); or one of drugs has adverse effects that are bad for the other drug.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I think I understand what you are trying to ask but this is really unclear.

Comment: What about now? :)

Comment: Much better :-)

Comment: Yes.. if you look up drug info then they say which drugs are incompatible with it. I don't know of a standard database but sites like [these](http://www.drugs.com/naproxen.html) are helpful. @Chris. are you going to sit in front of your comp on a nice saturday?? :P

Comment: @WYSIWYG Unfortunately, yes. bio.sx is nice for breaks inbetween. I got a load of work to be done until the end of next week.

Comment: If this question is not off topic I will explain some pharmacology to you but I think it is off

Comment: @caseyr547 Actually I was wondering about pharmacology in the first place, so that would be extremely useful.

Comment: @WYSIWYG is this off topic

Comment: @ctapobep i dont want to get in trouble so i will make sure its ok to post an answer first

Comment: I think you are referring to drug contraindications, which is a very large consideration and study in drug administration when multiple drugs are taken at a time. Many examples of drug-drug interactions can be found online such as here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_interaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to start by suggesting you talk to whoever prescribed you the drug or your pharmacist. They should be most up to date with interactions and there are some interactions which may only affect you more seriously because of your medical history or current conditions.

Here are some sites that you can check drug interactions in order of popularity:

[Medscape](http://reference.medscape.com/drug-interactionchecker)

[Drugs.com](http://www.drugs.com/drug_interactions.php)

[Healthline](http://www.healthline.com/druginteractions)

[WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/interaction-checker/)

[RxList](http://www.rxlist.com/drug-interaction-checker.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Drugs.com provides good lists of side effects when combining drugs. Just type (drug) interactions into Google and it should come up. Then you can click on a given drug and see how dangerous the two are together/what they can cause. Of course, your doctor is always the best resource.